# Oracle apex download CSV summary at run time not displaying

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle-apex

I have a report which is created as a public report. At runtime, I have created an aggregate for columns using

> Actions->Format->Group by

I used my *group by column* and then used *column* which has to be summed using *count* and *sum* as per my requirements

This is working. But when I try to download it using

> Actions->Download

and choose CSV format, this only shows *detail information* and not the final summary information.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this is expected - download won't display computations or aggregations.

Have a look at [Export your APEX Interactive Report to PDF](http://dgielis.blogspot.hr/2016/06/export-your-apex-interactive-report-to.html) written by Dimitri Gielis; if you scroll down, you'll see an option to use [Apex Office Print](https://www.apexofficeprint.com/index.html) which is NOT free, but - if you purchase it - it'll let you do what you're up to.